# Effects of tire pressure and loadout to motorbike's acceleration

Tags: pressure, acceleration

I often saw a tiny sticker about motorbike tire's pressure, which said that the front and rear tire's pressure for both riding alone and with a passanger were always same (29 psi for front tire and 33 psi for rear tire respectively). Assume that there's no other loadout on the motorbike, would motorbike's acceleration with 2 people (a rider and a passanger) on the motorbike be slower than with a rider only, if the motorbike's tire pressure was set to be same for both with a rider only and with a rider and a passanger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The acceleration of the bike is given by the torque of the engine and the mass of the bike plus passengers - so when you have a passenger, there is greater inertia to overcome and your acceleration will be less.

If you think about the role of friction, then when you have multiple passengers on the bike the normal force of the tire on the road will be proportionally greater; this will ensure that the force of friction (needed so the torque of the engine can be converted to forward momentum) will also be greater. In fact, with the passenger sitting on the back, the initial force on the rear wheel will be proportionally greater; but since the center of mass is further back, you are at greater risk of doing a wheelie.

Tire pressure is at most a secondary consideration for most road surfaces that you would want to ride a motorbike with passenger on.

Comment: Unless one or more tires is flat! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[Kinetic friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Kinetic_friction), $\mu_k$ is much less than [static friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Static_friction) $\mu_s$. When our (rolling) wheels maintain contact with the road, we say that we are in the static friction regime, whereas once they start skidding, we are in the kinetic friction regime.

The force of friction is typically (naively) modeled by $F_f \propto  \mu N$, whether static or kinetic (while both of these forces are vectors, the normal force acts perpendicular to the surface while friction acts in some direction parallel to the surface). If engine/gearbox can put enough torque on the axle to spin the wheels out, then the acceleration is capped not by the drive-train, but by the friction between the drive wheel(s) and the road.

Most tire manufacturers recommend a tire pressure which balances the durability of the tire's sidewall and the increased gas mileage of an over-inflated tire with the added comfort, acceleration and braking of a slightly less inflated tire (see [rolling resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance)). Obviously, tires either too flat or too full are a safety hazard.

If a motorcycle has a second rider (more weight, and more on the drive wheel), the question of whether it has more acceleration has a few considerations: Is the engine still strong enough to spin out the wheels? Is the bike's center mass now too high to accelerate with both wheels on the ground? Is [$\mu_s > 1$](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/friction-coefficients-d_778.html)? If the engine/gearbox are powerful enough, the center mass hasn't moved too high and the connection between the road and the wheels exceptionally tight, one could see greater acceleration with a passenger.

It's important to note that road conditions, variations in a tire's materials, tread, wear, inflation, the motorcycles, the riders, and the weather make all of this very difficult to predict without quite a few specifics. Your best bet is to run an experiment. Please consider the safety of yourself and others when designing and testing your proposition.

Comment: Are you saying "if you no longer spin your wheels because of the greater weight of the second passenger, you might accelerate faster"? Not sure what that has to do with tire pressure - or why you couldn't achieve the same thing by not going full throttle and a lighter load. Am I missing something subtle?

Comment: @Floris   The meat of the argument is in paragraph 3.  Basically, Coulomb's friction law is just a law (like Ohm's or Moore's), and contrary to Coulomb's Law's expectation, when rubber has more surface area in contact with the road, it has more friction because of how well it deforms locally. The subtlety is that for some tire/road combinations, since $\mu_s$ is greater than 1, more weight on the bike yields greater maximum acceleration. A slightly deflated tire similarly puts more rubber on the road.